# How to fetch the index number while doing a flatMap() on a Flux<String>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, flux, reactive

I have a code block as below

```
var x = Flux.just("A", "B", "C", "D");
        x.flatMap(y -> {
            System.out.println(y);
            return Mono.just(y);
        }).subscribe();
```

This successfully prints:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Is there a way I can print the index/record number as well in addition to the String value?

```
A - 1
B - 2
C - 3
D - 4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [index()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#index--):

```
x.index()
 .flatMap(y -> {
     System.out.println(y.getT2() + "-" + y.getT1());
     return Mono.just(y);
 })
 .subscribe();
```